# Using .htaccess to do product filtering on existing site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In a custom CMS I build I'm using the following for my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When a user hits **www.mysite.com** a script determines the page to load based on a slug of the page in the database. This is working fine, however I want to take it one step further. Right now I can do **www.mysite.com/products** and it will serve me the data for the products page. What I want to do is add product filtering to the URL. For example:

**www.mysite.com/products/collection/summer-collection**

or

**www.mysite.com/products/mens-navy-blue-blazer-19285**

or

**www.mysite.com/products/category/outer-wear**

I do have the Product Creation module generating a unique product slug already, so I just need to be able to modify my .htaccess to get this working.

Comment: What you have there is a boring catch-all RewriteRule block. Dispatching the actual `REQUEST_URI` on path sections is left to PHP in such cases (often called "front controller pattern"). Doesn't really make sense to introduce more directed match rules into your `.htaccess`.

Comment: Okay, so right now my "page check" file that handles the dispatching works like this: `$request = strip_tags(trim($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']));
 $request = rtrim($request, "/"); // remove trailing slash` so maybe I just need to do further evaluation of the parameter / individual pieces once exploded using `explode('/', $request);`. Am I on the rain train of thought there? Sorry, I'm newer to .htaccess so this is all a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Yes, something like that. You'll often want to use regexps for that later on. Just splitting doesn't always suffice. Look into the various routing frameworks/libraries. (Though that's often overkill.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into doing some regex for the checks, though I'm even worse at regex than I am .htaccess. One thing, however, is that right now if I do **www.mysite.com/products/literally-anything** I get a 404. What needs to change within the htaccess file to allow for two parameters to be sent instead of just one?

Comment: Probably needs `RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php`, but check the logs for what it really tried to access. Also the RewriteBase and <IfModule> wrapping are likely redundant.

Comment: Okay, I got it so it's not giving my pre-canned 404 error. It was something I had hard-coded in the script. the issue now is that when I go a level deeper with the URL, the site tries to load the CSS and other assets from that location instead of the root.

Comment: Figured it out. I was using relative paths which couldn't be overridden by .htaccess, as it turns out. Changed to absolute paths and it's working fine. Thanks for your help, Mario.